# Designing a friendships database structure: Should I use a multivalued column?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, normalization, relational-theory

Say I have a table called `User_FriendList`, which has the following characteristics:

```
CREATE TABLE User_FriendList (
    ID ...,
    User_ID...,
    FriendList_IDs...,
    CONSTRAINT User_Friendlist_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

And let us suppose that said table holds the following data:

```
 +----+---------+---------------------------+
 | ID | User_ID | Friendlist_IDs            |
 +----+---------+---------------------------+
 | 1  | 102     | 2:15:66:35:26:17:         |
 +----+---------+---------------------------+
 | 2  | 114     | 1:12:63:33:24:16:102      |
 +----+---------+---------------------------+
 | 3  | 117     | 6:24:52:61:23:90:97:118   |
 +----+---------+---------------------------+
```

*Note:* The “:” (colon) is the delimiter when *exploding* in PHP into an `array`.

**Questions**

So:

- Is this a convenient way to “store” the `IDs` of a `FriendList`?
- Or, instead, should I have individual rows with only one single `FriendId` value in each of them and, when I need to retrieve all the rows of a given *list*, simply perform a query like `SELECT * FROM UserFriendList WHERE UserId = 1`?

Comment: I recommend you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: It is a somewhat convenient way to store the IDs, as long as you are not planning to do anything with them and don't particularly care about data quality.

Comment: I think https://www.codedodle.com/2014/12/social-network-friends-database.html could be one of the best solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Managing an individual piece of information

Assuming that, in your business domain,

- a *User* can have zero-one-or-many *Friends*;
- a *Friend* must first be registered as a *User*; and
- you will search for, and/or add, and/or remove, and/or modify, single values of a *Friend List*;

then *each* specific datum gathered in the `Friendlist_IDs` multivalued column represents *a separate piece of information* that carries a very exact meaning. Therefore, said column

- entails a proper group of explicit constraints, and
- its values have the potential of being manipulated individually by means of several relational operations (or combinations thereof).

## Short answer

Consequently, you should retain each of the `Friendlist_IDs` values in (a) a column that accepts exclusively one sole value per row in (b) a table that represents the *conceptual-level* association type that can take place between *Users*, i.e., a *Friendship* —as I will exemplify in the following sections—.

In this way, you will be able to handle (i) said table as a *mathematical relation* and (ii) said column as a mathematical relation *attribute* —as much as MySQL and its SQL dialect permit, of course—.

**Why?**

Because the [relational model of data](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685), created by [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm), demands having tables that are composed of columns that hold *exactly one* value of the applicable *domain* or *type* per row; hence, declaring a table with a column that can contain more than one value of the domain or type in question (1) does not represent a *mathematical relation* and (2) would not permit obtaining the advantages proposed in the aforementioned theoretical framework.

## Modeling *Friendships* between *Users*: Defining the business environment rules first

I highly recommend starting to shape a database delimiting —before anything else— the corresponding *conceptual* schema by virtue of the definition of the relevant *business rules* that, among other factors, must describe the types of interrelationships that exist between the distinct aspects of interest, i.e., the applicable *entity types* and their *properties*; e.g.:

- A *User* is primarily identified by his or her *UserId*
- A *User* is alternately identified by the combination of his or her *FirstName*, *LastName*, *Gender*, and *Birthdate*
- A *User* is alternately identified by his or her *Username*
- A *User* is the *Requester* of zero-one-or-many *Friendships*
- A *User* is the *Addressee* of zero-one-or-many *Friendships*
- A *Friendship* is primarily identified by the combination of its *RequesterId* and its *AddresseeId*

**Expository IDEF1X diagram**

In this manner, I was able to derive the IDEF1X<sup>**1**</sup> diagram shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96be4.png), which integrates most of the rules previously formulated:

[image: Figure 1. User Friendships IDEF1X Diagram]

As depicted, *Requester* and *Addressee* are denotations that express the *Roles* carried out by the specific *Users* that take part in a given *Friendship*.

That being so, the *Friendship* entity type portrays an association type of *many-to-many* (M:N) cardinality ratio that can involve *different* ocurrences of the *same* entity type, i.e., *User*. As such, it is an example of the classic construct known as “Bill of Materials” or “Parts Explosion”.

---

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)) is a highly recommendable technique that was established as a *standard* in December 1993 by the U.S. *National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST). It is solidly based on (a) the early theoretical material authored by the *sole originator* of the relational model, i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [entity-relationship](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440) view of data, developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown.</sub>

---

**Illustrative SQL-DDL logical design**

Then, from the IDEF1X diagram presented above, declaring a DDL arrangement like the one that follows is much more “natural”:

```
-- You should determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all the table columns 
-- depending on your business context characteristics.

-- At the physical level, you should make accurate tests 
-- to define the mostconvenient INDEX strategies based on 
-- the pertinent query tendencies.

-- As one would expect, you are free to make use of 
-- your preferred (or required) naming conventions. 

CREATE TABLE UserProfile ( -- Represents an independent entity type.
    UserId          INT      NOT NULL,
    FirstName       CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    BirthDate       DATE     NOT NULL,
    GenderCode      CHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
    Username        CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_PK  PRIMARY KEY (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_AK1 UNIQUE ( -- Composite ALTERNATE KEY.
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        GenderCode,
        BirthDate
    ),
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_AK2 UNIQUE (Username) -- Single-column ALTERNATE KEY.
);

CREATE TABLE Friendship ( -- Stands for an associative entity type.
    RequesterId     INT      NOT NULL,
    AddresseeId     INT      NOT NULL, -- Fixed with a well-delimited data type.
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT Friendship_PK            PRIMARY KEY (RequesterId, AddresseeId), -- Composite PRIMARY KEY.
    CONSTRAINT FriendshipToRequester_FK FOREIGN KEY (RequesterId)
        REFERENCES UserProfile (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT FriendshipToAddressee_FK FOREIGN KEY (AddresseeId)
        REFERENCES UserProfile (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT FriendsAreDistinct_CK    CHECK       (RequesterId <> AddresseeId)
);
```

In this fashion:

- each *base table* represents an individual entity type;
- each *column* stands for a sole property of the *respective* entity type;
- a specific *data type*<sup>**a**</sup> is fixed for each *column* in order to guarantee that all the *values* it contains belong to a particular and well defined *set*, be it INT, DATETIME, CHAR, etc.; and
- multiple *constraints*<sup>**b**</sup> are configured (declaratively) in order to ensure that the assertions in the form of *rows* retained in all the *tables* meet the business rules determined at the conceptual schema.

## Advantages of a single-valued column

As demonstrated, you can, e.g.:

- Take advantage of *referential integrity* enforced by the database management system (DBMS for brevity) for the `Friendship.AddresseeId` column, since constraining it as a FOREIGN KEY (FK for brevity) that makes a reference to the `UserProfile.UserId` column guarantees that every value points to an *existing* row.
- Create a *composite* PRIMARY KEY (PK) made up of the combination of columns `(Friendship.RequesterId, Friendship.AddresseeId)`, helping to elegantly distinguish all the INSERTed rows and, naturally, protect their *uniqueness*.

  Of course, this means that the attachment of an *extra* column for system-assigned surrogate values (e.g., one set up with the [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) property in Microsoft SQL Server or with the [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute in MySQL) and the assisting INDEX is *entirely superfluous*.
- Restrict the retained values in `Friendship.AddresseeId` to a precise data type<sup>**c**</sup> (which should match, e.g., the one established for `UserProfile.UserId`, in this case INT), letting the DBMS take care of the pertinent *automatic* validation.

  This factor can as well help to (a) utilize of the corresponding built-in type functions and (b) optimize *disk space* usage.
- Optimize data *retrieval* at the physical level by configuring *small and fast* subordinate INDEXes for the `Friendship.AddresseeId` column, as these physical elements can substantialy assist in *speeding up* the queries that involve said column.

  Certainly, you can, e.g., put up a single-column INDEX for `Friendship.AddresseeId` alone, a multi-column one that encompasses `Friendship.RequesterId` and `Friendship.AddresseeId` , or both.
- Avoid the *unnecessary complexity* introduced by “searching for” distinct values that are collected together inside the same column (very likely duplicated, wrongly typed, etc.), a course of action that would eventually slow down the functioning of your system, because you would have to resort to resource- and time-consuming non-relational methods to accomplish said task.

So, there are multiple reasons that call for analyzing the relevant business environment carefully in order to mark out the *type*<sup>**d**</sup> of each table column with accuracy.

As expounded, the role played by the database designer is paramount to make the best use of (i) the *logical-level* benefits offered by the relational model and (ii) the *physical* mechanisms provided by the DBMS of choice.

---

<sub><sup>**a**, **b**, **c**, **d**</sup> Evidently, when working with SQL platforms (e.g., [Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-domn.html) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createdomain.html)) that support DOMAIN creation (a distinctive *relational* feature), you can declare columns that only accept values that belong to their respective (fittingly constrained and sometimes shared) DOMAINs.</sub>

---

**One or more application programs sharing the database under consideration**

When you have to employ `arrays` in the code of the application program(s) accesing the database, you simply need to retrieve the relevant data set(s) *in full* and then “bind” it (them) to the concerning code structure or execute the associated app(s) process(es) that should take place.

## Further benefits of single-valued columns: Database structure extensions are much more easy

Another advantage of holding the `AddresseeId` data point in its reserved and properly typed column is that it considerably facilitates extending the database structure, as I will exemplify below.

**Scenario progression: Incorporating the *Friendship Status* concept**

Since *Friendships* can evolve over time you might have to keep track of such a phenomenon, thus you would have to (1) expand the conceptual schema and (2) declare a few more tables in the logical layout. So, let us arrange the next business rules to delineate the new incorporations:

- A *Friendship* holds one-to-many *FriendshipStatuses*
- A *FriendshipStatus* is primarily identified by the combination of its *RequesterId*, its *AddresseeId* and its *SpecifiedDateTime*
- A *User* specifies zero-one-or-many *FriendshipStatuses*
- A *Status* classifies zero-one-or-many *FriendshipStatuses*
- A *Status* is primarily identified by its *StatusCode*
- A *Status* is alternately identified by its *Name*

**Extended IDEF1X diagram**

Successively, the previous IDEF1X diagram can be extended in order to include the new entity types and interrelationship types described above. A diagram depicting the previous elements associated with the new ones is presented in [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CkB5.png):

[image: Figure 2. Friendship Status IDEF1X Diagram]

**Logical structure additions**

Afterwards, we can lengthen the DDL layout with the following declarations:

```
--
CREATE TABLE MyStatus ( -- Denotes an independent entity type.
    StatusCode CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
    Name       CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT MyStatus_PK PRIMARY KEY (StatusCode),
    CONSTRAINT MyStatus_AK UNIQUE      (Name) -- ALTERNATE KEY.
); 

CREATE TABLE FriendshipStatus ( -- Represents an associative entity type.
    RequesterId       INT      NOT NULL,
    AddresseeId       INT      NOT NULL,
    SpecifiedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    StatusCode        CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
    SpecifierId       INT      NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT FriendshipStatus_PK             PRIMARY KEY (RequesterId, AddresseeId, SpecifiedDateTime), -- Composite PRIMARY KEY.
    CONSTRAINT FriendshipStatusToFriendship_FK FOREIGN KEY (RequesterId, AddresseeId)
        REFERENCES Friendship  (RequesterId, AddresseeId), -- Composite FOREIGN KEY.
    CONSTRAINT FriendshipStatusToMyStatus_FK   FOREIGN KEY (StatusCode)
        REFERENCES MyStatus    (StatusCode),
    CONSTRAINT FriendshipStatusToSpecifier_FK  FOREIGN KEY (SpecifierId)
        REFERENCES UserProfile (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT FriendsAreDifferent_CK          CHECK       (RequesterId <> AddresseeId)      
);
```

<sup>The creation of this DDL design, along with the previous excerpt, has been tested in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cbead850b6457698f63f0cdfcddf5623) that runs on SQL Server 2019.</sup>

Accordingly, every time that the *Status* of a given *Friendship* needs to be put up-to-date, the *Users* would only have to INSERT a new `FriendshipStatus` row, containing:

- the suitable `RequesterId` and `AddresseeId` values —taken from the concerning `Friendship` row—;
- the new and meaningful `StatusCode` value —drawn from `MyStatus.StatusCode`—;
- the exact INSERTion instant, i.e., `SpecifiedDateTime` —preferably using a server function so that you can retrieve and retain it in a reliable manner—; and
- the `SpecifierId` value that would indicate the respective `UserId` that entered the new `FriendshipStatus` into the system —ideally, with the aid of your app(s) facilities—.

To that extent, let us suppose that the `MyStatus` table encloses the following data —with PK values that are (a) end user-, app programmer- and DBA-friendly and (b) small and fast in terms of bytes at the *physical* implementation level—:

```
 +-——————————-+-—————————-+
 | StatusCode | Name      | 
 +-——————————-+-—————————-+
 | R          | Requested |
 +------------+-----------+
 | A          | Accepted  |
 +------------+-----------+
 | D          | Declined  |
 +------------+-----------+
 | B          | Blocked   |
 +------------+-----------+
```

So, the `FriendshipStatus` table may hold data like shown below:

```
 +-———————————-+-———————————-+-———————————————————————-+-——————————-+-———————————-+
 | RequesterId | AddresseeId | SpecifiedDateTime       | StatusCode | SpecifierId |
 +-———————————-+-———————————-+-———————————————————————-+-——————————-+-———————————-+
 |        1750 |        1748 | 2016-04-01 16:58:12.000 | R          |        1750 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        1750 |        1748 | 2016-04-02 09:13:08.000 | A          |        1748 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        1750 |        1748 | 2016-04-02 11:02:06.000 | B          |        1748 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
```

As you can see, it can be said that the `FriendshipStatus` table serves the purpose of comprising a *time series*.

---

## Responses to comments

### Data manipulation

> I know this is super old and maybe a dumb (sic) question but, I've been studying this and have been wondering how you'd go about simply getting a user's current friendship status with someone using the FriendshipStatus table. – [@Timothy Fisher](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/213570), on [2020-08-05 02:24:16Z](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135941/designing-a-friendships-database-structure-should-i-use-a-multivalued-column/135966#comment535708_135966)

First of all, there is nothing wrong with your question and, although this is a design Q & A and data manipulation is a separate and subsequent task, explaining how to get the current or most-recent *Status* of a given *Friendship* can definitely assist in showing the advantages of the proposed layout (and therefore it can help a future reader).

Here the key is approaching the relevant data in terms of *sets*, since that is one of the main puroposes of adopting a relational frame of mind.

**Deriving the current *Status* of a *Friendship***

Let us suppose that we are working with the following information in the `FriendhipStatus` table:

```
 +-———————————-+-———————————-+-———————————————————————-+-——————————-+-———————————-+
 | RequesterId | AddresseeId | SpecifiedDateTime       | StatusCode | SpecifierId |
 +-———————————-+-———————————-+-———————————————————————-+-——————————-+-———————————-+
 |        1750 |        1748 | 2016-04-01 16:58:12.000 | R          |        1750 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        1750 |        1748 | 2016-04-02 09:13:08.000 | A          |        1748 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        1750 |        1748 | 2016-04-02 11:02:06.000 | B          |        1748 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        1825 |        4247 | 2016-05-11 16:28:03.000 | R          |        1825 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        1825 |        4247 | 2016-05-11 19:18:09.000 | A          |        4247 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        1748 |        5342 | 2016-06-11 11:13:05.000 | R          |        1748 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        1748 |        5342 | 2016-06-12 19:03:07.000 | D          |        5342 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        3691 |        1750 | 2016-06-20 16:28:05.000 | R          |        3691 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        3691 |        1750 | 2016-06-20 16:51:10.000 | A          |        1750 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
 |        3691 |        1750 | 2016-06-21 08:05:05.000 | B          |        1750 |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
```

And say we want to obtain the current *Status* of the *Friendship* between the *User* primarily identified by the *UserId* 1750 and the *User* primarily identified by the *UserId* 1748.

A very good option is employing what is commonly known as a *subquery*, i.e., a nested DML operation (in this case a SELECT):

```
SELECT FS.StatusCode AS CurrentStatusCode
  FROM FriendshipStatus FS
 WHERE FS.RequesterId = 1750 --(a)
   AND FS.AddresseeId = 1748 --(b)
   AND FS.SpecifiedDateTime = (
                                  SELECT MAX(NestedFS.SpecifiedDateTime)
                                        FROM FriendshipStatus NestedFS
                                       WHERE NestedFS.RequesterId = FS.RequesterId
                                         AND NestedFS.AddresseeId = FS.AddresseeId
                              );
-- (a), (b) Those “fixed” values can of course be replaced by parameters.
```

In this manner, we would be exclusively deriving the `CurrentStatusCode` —contextual alias for `FriendshipStatus.StatusCode`— in a scalar column in the *main* SELECT operation. The *nested* SELECT gets the latest `FriendshipStatus.SpecifiedDateTime` value —via the MAX() function— for the corresponding *Friendship*, i.e., the `RequesterId` and `AddresseeId` values assigned in the *main* SELECT, and these three values are in turn used as conditions in the *main* WHERE clause. As a result, we derive the following column and value for the *Requester* 1750 and the *Addressee* 1748:

```
 +-—————————————————-+
 | CurrentStatusCode |
 +-—————————————————-+
 | B                 |
 +-—————————————————-+
```

Which means that one of the *Friends* involved blocked the other.

And if you want to obtain more information about that *Friendship* along with the current *Status*, you simply have to incorporate more relevant columns to the *main* SELECT:

```
SELECT FS.RequesterId,
       FS.AddresseeId,
       FS.SpecifiedDateTime,       
       FS.StatusCode AS CurrentStatusCode,
       FS.SpecifierId
  FROM FriendshipStatus FS
 WHERE FS.RequesterId = 1750
   AND FS.AddresseeId = 1748
   AND FS.SpecifiedDateTime = (
                                  SELECT MAX(NestedFS.SpecifiedDateTime)
                                        FROM FriendshipStatus NestedFS
                                       WHERE NestedFS.RequesterId = FS.RequesterId
                                         AND NestedFS.AddresseeId = FS.AddresseeId
                              );
```

Having all those data points you would know, e.g., who “blocked” who and when.

**Views**

If you are interested in simplifying future code regarding *Status* data retrieval (and make it more “readable”), you can create a view (i.e. a derived table) that, e.g., “hides” the subquery, and you can subsequently SELECT directly from said view.

***Physical-level* settings**

Of course, in order to speed up data manipulation performance you have to take care of the design settings at the *physical* level of abstraction; e.g., the involved tables should be supported by single- and/or multi-column INDEXes, taking into account, e.g., the order of the columns involved in WHERE conditions. Then you should evaluate the data manipulation tendencies with respect to all the relevant INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT and DELETE operations.

You could as well evaluate the implementation of “materialized” views.

All the DML code samples shown above, the sample data and other relevant aspects are included in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c37cf74c9d234b8e687069bd25ea28f) so that you can see these exercises “in action”.

### Data constraints

> It seems this would allow `Friendship`s to be made from a user to themselves, e.g. `RequesterId` and `AddresseeId` being the same. Is it possible to prevent this on the DBMS side without triggers? Also, can an `ON DELETE CASCADE` be introduced to both FKs in the `Friendship` table, e.g. deleting it if a `Friend` on one side is deleted? I tried creating such a table but at least SQL Server rejected the table creation due to possible cyclic / multiple cascade paths. – [@Ray](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/250123), on [2022-03-26 15:54:22Z](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135941/designing-a-friendships-database-structure-should-i-use-a-multivalued-column/135966#comment604142_135966)

**CHECK constraint**

Yes, you certainly can prevent the values retained in the columns `Friendship.RequesterId` and `Friendship.AddresseeId` from being identical in the same row without triggers (which, as you know, should be left as a *very* last resort). In this case I would make use of a CHECK constraint (that i just added to the DDL logical layout shown in prior sections), which allows handling this requirement declaratively (in contrast to the sub-optimal procedural option with TRIGGERs):

```
CONSTRAINT FriendsAreDistinct_CK CHECK (RequesterId <> AddresseeId);
```

So, if you want to INSERT, e.g., the row that follows:

```
INSERT INTO Friendship 
    (RequesterId, AddresseeId, CreatedDateTime)
VALUES
    (1750, 1750, '2022-03-31 16:58:12.000');
```

…the DBMS (in your case SQL Server) should reject that row and throw a message like this one:

```
Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 2
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "FriendsAreDistinct_CK". The conflict occurred in database "Foo", table "dbo.Friendship".
Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 2
The statement has been terminated.
```

**Existence dependencies and TRANSACTIONs**

An important aspect that should be treated carefully when creating the database structure and the related constraints has to do with (1) the order in the creation of the tables and (2) the order of the creation of the constraints, since these factors are instrumental in the representation of the existence dependencies that take place in the business context of concern, so please make sure that you first create the “independent” tables, then continue creating the ones that depend on the existence and constraints of those and so on. As demonstrated in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cbead850b6457698f63f0cdfcddf5623) running on SQL Server 2019, no issue came about when creating the database structure and constraints.

In that same regard, if you have to DELETE a row that has FK references, instead of using ON DELETE CASCADE actions (which tend to consume a lot of DBMS resources) I suggest that you carry out the required manipulation operations via TRANSACTIONs, and in order to optimize DBMS resources you also have to take into account the existence dependencies of the concerning data. In this way, you would first DELETE the “dependent” rows (in the conceptual hierarchy) and once all those “dependent” rows have been deleted then you carry out the DELETE of the “main” row of interest, all of this in a single TRANSACTION. Similar considerations apply for UPDATES, thus the data hierarchy also has to be respected in order to optimize the data manipulation processes at the physical level.

Let us assume that due to a certain reason you have to DELETE a certain *UserProfile* and all of its related info, so you would proceed deleting

1. all the related rows in the `FriendshipStatus` table, then
2. all the related rows in the `Friendship` table, and after that
3. the exact row of concern in the `UserProfile` table.

All of the above in that specific order, inside the same TRANSACTION, so as to guarantee that all the operations are either committed or discarded as a single unit of work by the DBMS.

**Note:** In agreement with the previous deliberations, it is very important to point out that all the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations of a given database should be performed *exclusively* within TRANSACTIONs inside stored procedures which only some privileged database users can execute. This strategy optimizes data integrity protection in particular and database management in general.

**Further constraints**

Generally, in scenarios like the one discussed here, a designer has to set up further data constraints, but I am not going to address those aspects because it can be a very didactic endeavour for future readers, and as you know, constraints can change from one business context to the other.

### Additional considerations on the `Friendship` and `FriendshipStatus` tables

> Could you explain little bit more why do we need `Friendship` table? I imagine if user would like to request friendship with other user it would mean `INSERT` into `FriendshipStatus` table with status code `R`. Then if receiver accepts it then it is another insert with status code `A`. It seems all relevant data would be kept there - I am confused why do need to store combination of those user ids in another table? Isn't content of `Friendship` duplicated in `FriendshipStatus`? Basically if there is combination of userId1 and userId2 in `FriendshipStatus` it goes to `Friendship` table. Why? – [@Piotr](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/255701), on [2022-07-30 19:08:10Z](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135941/designing-a-friendships-database-structure-should-i-use-a-multivalued-column/135966#comment613999_135966)

If I address your inquiries here in the answer body I hit the  “limit of 30000 characters” within just a few more paragraphs, and the comment box is not well suited for a proper reply (comments are meant to be transient, offer very poor formatting options, permit even fewer characters, etc.), therefore I have uploaded my reply to your questions in [this external file](https://drive.proton.me/urls/803N2XFDXW#xtYhq98tZLnf).

---

## Relevant posts

You might as well be interested in:

- [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128332/63644) in which I suggest a basic method to deal with a common many-to-many relationship between two dissimilar entity types.
- The IDEF1X diagram shown in Figure 1 that illustrates [this other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104619/63644). Pay special attention to the entity types named *Marriage* and *Progeny*, because they are two more examples of how to handle the “Parts Explosion Problem”.
- [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130489/63644) that presents a brief deliberation about holding different pieces of information within a single column.

Comment: I know this is super old and maybe a dumb question but, I've been studying this and have been wondering how you'd go about simply getting a user's current friendship status with someone using the FriendshipStatus table.

Comment: It seems this would allow `Friendship`s to be made from a user to themselves, e.g. `RequesterId` and `AddresseeId` being the same. Is it possible to prevent this on the DBMS side without triggers? Also, can an `ON DELETE CASCADE` be introduced to both FKs in the `Friendship` table, e.g. deleting it if a `Friend` on one side is deleted? I tried creating such a table but at least SQL Server rejected the table creation due to possible cyclic / multiple cascade paths.

Comment: @TimothyFisher It's been a while since you posted that comment but I just addressed it directly in the answer, in the new section accordingly entitled  “Responses to comments - Data manipulation”, better late than never.

Comment: @Ray I just addressed your inquiries in the new section entitled “Responses to comments - Data constraints”.

Comment: @MDCCL Thank you! I added a "no self-friending" check to my table. In fact, I'm required to teach Entity Framework to create the DB (code-first) and got it to add that check. It also set `ON DELETE CASCADE` by default, and I've disabled that for this table now (as I have to carry out the user deletion "manually" anyway) - and SQL Server no longer has an issue creating the tables.

Comment: Could you explain little bit more why do we need `Friendship` table? I imagine if user would like to request friendship with other user it would mean `INSERT` into `FriendshipStatus` table with status code `R`. Then if receiver accepts it then it is another insert with status code `A`. It seems all relevant data would be kept there - I am confused why do need to store combination of those user ids in another table? Isn't content of `Friendship` duplicated in `FriendshipStatus`? Basically if there is combination of userId1 and userId2 in `FriendshipStatus` it goes to `Friendship` table. Why?

Comment: @Piotr I have just addressed those points in the new section entitled “Additional considerations on the `Friendship` and `FriendshipStatus` tables”.