# Should I create multiple tables for different entity states, statuses or stages?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a `tasks` table in my database and, in the business domain of interest, *tasks* can have multiple *states*: “open”, “begun”, “in review” and “completed”.

Despite having “open” and “begun” in the same table, identified using *flags*, I decided for some reason early on to have “in review” and “completed”  *tasks* in their own separate tables. While this seemed like a good idea to start off with, making it easy to query for specific things, when I thought about implementing a *comment* feature for *tasks* I realised that the `task_id` value would be changing across the three tables.

Have I gone about this all wrong?

**Current considerations**

Some solutions I thought up would be to redo the organisation and put everything in one table, using *flags* to differentiate purely between the *states* (this would lead to a fair amount of reworking); to create some kind of `UUID` that is transferable across the tables - though I think there might issues with performance if this is done; and finally, to set the `IDs` across the tables to be no-longer *auto incremented* and to simply “inherit” the original value from the first `task` table (which *auto increments*).

What's the done thing in this situation? I'm not the most versed in database design and I'm kind of making this up as I go along.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Responses to further information requests made by @MDCCL via comments**

> So, the *state* (or *status*) of a *task* can change over time, right? How many times can the same concrete *task* present the same *state*, let us say, “open”? Will it vary depending on the *kind* of *state* presented by the relevant *task*?

Yes, a *task.state* could theoretically change up to four times. I won't go into specifics of the logic but the longest chain would be `“begun” → “completed” → “review” → “completed”`. And each time, currently, they're being put into another table.

The exception is whether it's “begun” or not, a *user* may abandon and then re-undertake the *task* infinitely - in theory at least. Which is at least helped by the fact that the “begun” status is a *flag*.

> Ok, but a certain *task* will present, at all times, exactly one particular “present” *state*, right? For example, when a `task` row is INSERTed, it should be accompannied by a certain `state` value, which I assume would be “open”. Later, the *state* of such a *task* will evolve to only one of the other possible *options*, that is, either “begun” or “in review” or “completed”.

Yea, that's exactly right. A *task* will always be in a *stage*, and can't be in multiple ones.

> Once a particular *task* is deemed as “completed”, can it change to another *state*?

Yes, it can be sent back to “review” if certain parameters are reached. And from “review” it can either go back to “begun” or back to “completed”.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way I see it, the fact that (a) a concrete *Task* can present distinct *States* at different points in time entails (b) the creation of a table that is going to contain a *time series*, as I will detail below.

## Business rules

In order to define the structure and constraints of a relational database, it is paramount to first identify and formulate the corresponding business domain rules (i.e., delineate the *conceptual schema*) with precision, taking into account the relevant *entity types*, *properties* and the corresponding  *interconnections*. In this way, some of the formulations that are especially significant in the scenario under consideration are:

- A *Task* presents one-to-many *StateSpecifications*
- A *Task* cannot present more than one *StateSpecification* at the same *Instant*
- A *StateSpecification* is considered *Current*

  - from the particular *Instant* in which it is entered
  - until the exact *Instant* when the successive
    *StateSpecification* is entered
- A *State* defines zero-one-or-many *StateSpecifications*
- A *Task* receives zero-one-or-many *Comments*

Consequently, based on the aforementioned formulations, I created the IDEF1X<sup>**†**</sup> diagram shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0iRc.png):

[image: Figure 1 - Tasks States and Comments IDEF1X Diagram]

As you can see, `Task` and `State` are depicted as individual entity types, each with its own group of properties (or attributes) and its own (direct) associations (or relationships), which are expressed via the corresponding *verb phrases*, *lines*, *cardinalities* and FOREIGN KEY (FK) marks.

The entity type denominated `StateSpecification`, associated with the two brought up before, is a central aspect in the solution I will explain below.

## Expository logical design and sample data

I shaped an expository logical design, based on the IDEF1X diagram above, by means of the DDL structure that follows:

```
-- You should determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all your table columns 
-- depending on your business context characteristics.

-- Also, you should make accurate tests to define the most
-- convenient physical implementation settings; e.g.,
-- a good indexing strategy based on query tendencies.

-- As one would expect, you are free to use your 
-- preferred or required naming conventions. 

CREATE TABLE Task (
    TaskNumber      INT      NOT NULL,
    Description     CHAR(90) NOT NULL,
    Etcetera        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT Task_PK  PRIMARY KEY (TaskNumber)
);    

CREATE TABLE State (
    StateCode   CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
    Name        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Description CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT State_PK  PRIMARY KEY (StateCode),
    CONSTRAINT State_AK1 UNIQUE      (Name),       -- ALTERNATE KEY.
    CONSTRAINT State_AK2 UNIQUE      (Description) -- ALTERNATE KEY.
); 

CREATE TABLE StateSpecification (
    TaskNumber        INT      NOT NULL,
    SpecifiedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    StateCode         CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT StateSpecification_PK         PRIMARY KEY (TaskNumber, SpecifiedDateTime), -- Composite PRIMARY KEY.
    CONSTRAINT StateSpecification_to_Task_FK FOREIGN KEY (TaskNumber)
        REFERENCES Task  (TaskNumber),
    CONSTRAINT StateSpecification_to_State   FOREIGN KEY (StateCode)
        REFERENCES State (StateCode)    
);

CREATE TABLE TaskComment (
    TaskNumber      INT      NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Body            TEXT     NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT TaskComment_PK      PRIMARY KEY (TaskNumber, CreatedDateTime),
    CONSTRAINT TaskComment_to_Task FOREIGN KEY (TaskNumber)
        REFERENCES Task (TaskNumber)  
);

--
--
```

**The State table**

The `State` table previously illustrated fulfills a *look-up* role, and is meant to contain five rows (as per the five *State* samples you provided):

```
 +-—————————-+-—————————-+-———————————————-+
 | StateCode | Name      | Description     |
 +-—————————-+-—————————-+-———————————————-+
 | O         | Open      | Indicates that… |
 +-----------+-----------+-----------------+
 | B         | Begun     | Indicates that… |
 +-----------+-----------+-----------------+
 | R         | In review | Indicates that… |
 +-----------+-----------+-----------------+
 | C         | Completed | Indicates that… |
 +-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Note the definition of a PRIMARY KEY (PK) constraint on a column retaining values that are, at the same time, *meaninfgul* (regarding interpretation by end users and technicians) and *small* (in terms of bytes at the *physical* implementation level), which makes it both readable and fast regarding, e.g., data retrieval.

If new business domain *States* arise, you can of course INSERT the corresponding rows INTO the `State` table.

**The State Specification table**

Now, suposse that *Task no. 1750* presents the following *State History* in the form of (unordered) rows held in the `StateSpecification` table:

```
 +-——————————-+-———————————————————————-+-—————————-+
 | TaskNumber | SpecifiedDateTime       | StateCode |
 +-——————————-+-———————————————————————-+-—————————-+
 | 1750       | 2016-12-01 16:58:12.000 | O         |
 +------------+-------------------------+-----------+
 | 1750       | 2016-12-02 09:12:05.000 | B         |
 +------------+-------------------------+-----------+
 | 1750       | 2016-12-04 10:57:01.000 | R         |
 +------------+-------------------------+-----------+
 | 1750       | 2016-12-07 07:33:08.000 | C         |
 +------------+-------------------------+-----------+
 | 1750       | 2016-12-08 12:12:09.000 | R         |
 +------------+-------------------------+-----------+
 | 1750       | 2016-12-08 19:46:01.000 | B         |
 +------------+-------------------------+-----------+
 | 1750       | 2016-12-09 06:24:07.000 | R         |
 +------------+-------------------------+-----------+
 | 1750       | 2016-12-11 07:24:07.000 | C         |
 +------------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

As demonstrated, each value in the `SpecifiedDateTime` column indicates the precise point in time in which a given *Task* (via the `TaskNumber`) started presenting a particular *State* (by virtue of `StateCode`).

Seeing that the `StateCode` column keeps values that have a quite clear intention, it helps to save the usage of a JOIN clause. It is paramount to make clear that this does *not* imply that JOINs are something detrimental (they are, in fact, fundamental and powerful instruments in any relational database) but, whenever suitable, reducing the consumption of the valuable resources of the system is decidedly practical.

**The Comment table**

The `Comment` table, as exemplified above, can easily be related to the `Task` table via a FK constraint definition, because the PK value of a `Task` will remain the same, no matter if its *State* undergoes zero, one or more modifications.

I assume that, in the business context of relevance, a *Comment* (a) will always depend on the existence of a *Task* occurrence and (b) will always belong to the same indidivual *Task* occurrence; therefore, I defined the `Comment` table with a composite PK that incorporates the PK column of `Task` and the exact `DateTime` in which a particular `Comment` was created. Apart from that, you might like to evaluate the attachment of a column for system-controled surrogates (e.g., a column with the [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute in MySQL) to this table, it may or may not offer a better execution performance (probably not), so carrying out some thorough testing sessions would clarify the case (a *non*-data addition, as is the case of columns holding system-controled surrogates, should always be well assessed and justified).

## Data derivation code samples

There are some important data points that will very likely be required with respect to the scenario in question, but they should be obtained as *derived* (or *calculated*) values.

For example, if you need to obtain the `CurrentState` for *Task no. 1750*, you can derive it with the next SELECT statement:

```
SELECT T.TaskNumber,
       SS.StateCode AS CurrentStateCode,
       SS.SpecifiedDateTime
     FROM Task T
     JOIN StateSpecification SS
       ON T.TaskNumber = SS.TaskNumber 
    WHERE T.TaskNumber = 1750 -- You can provide a parameter instead of a fixed value.
      AND SS.SpecifiedDateTime = (
                                    SELECT MAX(SpecifiedDateTime)
                                          FROM StateSpecification InnerSS
                                         WHERE T.TaskNumber = InnerSS.TaskNumber
                                 );
```

When you face the necessity to get the `CurrentState` for all Tasks, you can declare a statement like the one that follows:

```
SELECT T.TaskNumber,
       SS.StateCode AS CurrentStateCode,
       SS.SpecifiedDateTime
     FROM Task T
     JOIN StateSpecification SS
       ON T.TaskNumber = SS.TaskNumber
    WHERE SS.SpecifiedDateTime = (
                                    SELECT MAX(SpecifiedDateTime)
                                          FROM StateSpecification InnerSS
                                         WHERE T.TaskNumber = InnerSS.TaskNumber
                                 );
```

If you have to derive the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of all the `StateSpecifications` that correspond to *Task no. 1750*, you may utilize:

```
SELECT T.TaskNumber,
       T.Description,
       SS.StateCode,
       SS.SpecifiedDateTime AS StartDateTime,
       (
          SELECT MIN(SpecifiedDateTime)
                FROM StateSpecification InnerSS
               WHERE T.TaskNumber = InnerSS.TaskNumber
                 AND InnerSS.SpecifiedDateTime > SS.SpecifiedDateTime
       ) AS EndDateTime
    FROM Task T
    JOIN StateSpecification SS
      ON T.TaskNumber = SS.TaskNumber
   WHERE T.TaskNumber = 1750 -- You can provide a parameter instead of a fixed value.
ORDER BY StartDateTime DESC;
```

In case you must obtain the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of all the `StateSpecifications`, i.e., the *whole period* in which they were *current*:

```
SELECT T.TaskNumber,
       T.Description,
       SS.StateCode,
       SS.SpecifiedDateTime AS StartDateTime,
       (
          SELECT MIN(SpecifiedDateTime)
                FROM StateSpecification InnerSS
               WHERE T.TaskNumber = InnerSS.TaskNumber
                 AND InnerSS.SpecifiedDateTime > SS.SpecifiedDateTime
       ) AS EndDateTime
    FROM Task T
    JOIN StateSpecification SS
      ON T.TaskNumber = SS.TaskNumber
ORDER BY StartDateTime DESC;
```

**VIEW definitions**

Naturally, one or more of the SELECT statements displayed above can be set up as VIEWs, so that you can arrive at, e.g., the pertinent information directly FROM one single *table* (a *derived* one, yes, but it would still be a table).

**Demos**

I created live demos of the code here deliberated [in this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4100a8/1) (running on MySQL 5.6) and [in this db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b6a3f98991f12e33bb68fa19b5c1372d) (running on Microsoft SQL Server 2014, if someone is interested).

## Responses to comments

> I think I shall have to go about performing this modification, and think the system will benefit from the additional functionality of the `StateSpecification` table. It goes to show that good database design can accommodate all our needs without making things messy.

I could not agree more with your second assertion. A database that is designed properly (conceptually, logically and physically), usually becomes a *key* element in a software development project. If a *relational* database *reflects* the business context of interest with accuracy, it can —to be brief— ease its maintenance substantially and offer vast versatility. That is why it is very useful to analyze carefully the structure of the relevant *things*, to observe them in terms of *what* they are in the real world, and then represent them with precision in a database implementation.

The data, in and of itself, is a highly valuable organizational asset and, a consequence, it should be administered as such. A reliable manner to achieve said objective is employing technical means that are supported on sound theory, and in the field of data management there is nothing more sound than [the relational model](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685). This is in agreement with the [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm)’s 1981 Turing Award Lecture, entitled [*Relational Database: A Practical Foundation for Productivity*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1283937&CFID=882088122&CFTOKEN=78713693).

> Also, just to clarify, the `StateSpecification` table has to be updated manually on every change of state, correct?

Basically yes, the `StateSpecification` table has to be brought up to date each time that a *Task* presents a *State* change. This procedure should be performed by way of an INSERT operation that introduces a new `StateSpecification` row that should include a FK value that points to the `Task` row that applies.

It is opportune to stress that when a `Task` row is INSERTed, it will have to present a `StateSpecification` indicating the *State* deemed as ‘Open’ (by dint of an ‘O’ value retained in the `StateCode` column), hence you should make use of well defined [ACID TRANSACTIONS](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1) so that both the `Task` row and its `StateSpecification` counterpart are treated as a *single unit*. In this manner, the two respective INSERT operations can either succeed or fail as a whole, maintaining the involved data *consistent* with the identified business rules.

## Comparable scenario

You might find of help

- [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135966/63644),

as it includes a case that has similar features.

---

**Endnotes**

<sub><sup>**†**</sup> *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)) is a highly recommendable data modeling technique that was established as a *standard* in December 1993 by the United States *National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST). It is solidly based on (a) the early theoretical work authored by the originator of the relational model, i.e., Dr. E. F. Codd; on (b) the [Entity-Relationship view](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown.</sub>

Comment: In all my time on the Stack websites, I think this is quite possibly the greatest answer I have received. Thank you ever so much for such a detailed response. I think I shall have to go about performing this modification, and think the system will benefit from the additional functionality of the `StateSpecification` table. It goes to show that good database design can accommodate all our needs without making things messy. Thank you once again.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the `StateSpecification` table has to be updated manually on every change of state, correct?

Comment: @Mackey18 I'm glad to make a contribution, you are most welcome.

Comment: I look forward to it. Mention me in a comment when you update it, I'm very eager to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly at this point you would do better to go back and put everything into one table. I'm going to assume that your other two tables have additional information on them, that isn't on the "base" table.

You can handle that by either having nullable columns or providing default data that you can safely ignore in your business logic in your app. Alternately you can keep the other two tables but consolidate the common functionality into the base table. Then as you query, if an inner join returns the record in both tables, it must be in that status. (however, this also allows for some auditing tricks later as well, which I'm not going into right now)

Because you want to track a singular event through the system of processing, you should have a singular table to track that entity. You can have child tables for additional detail, but what you've described is either three distinct models or a broken schema.

I would pursue consolidation.

Comment: Yep, it seems this is exactly what I'll have to do. Thank you for the detailed reply, it is greatly appreciated. Nullable field also makes sense for the extra information.