# Is it a good to move data out of the original table when it's deleted or archived?

Tags: database-design

I have a table with **offers** where I perform typical CRUD actions.

Each offer can has one out of the following statuses: **active**, **deleted**, **archived**, **withdrawn**, etc.

Most actions I perform only for **active** offers, so is it a good idea to move offers with other statuses to other tables, like **offers_archived**, **offers_withdrawn**?

Comment: If your question applies to a relational database built on a certain SQL database management system, then you might be interested in implementing *temporal* capabilities, as detailed [in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107575/63644). Although, as per your description of the scenario at hand (which seems to imply keeping track of the *status* of a certain type of entity), you may find of help the deliberations contained [in this series of posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158980).

Comment: Really, this will depend a lot on how the data is used. You say most actions you take only involve active offers. Are you the primary/sole user of the table in question? If not, how would this impact how others use the table? What statuses have the highest record counts? (if almost all records are active, then this would have minimal impact) Would this require changes to any existing applications, reports, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

Data has a place to be based on what it *is*. Moving it somewhere else such as to an *archive* table or a *deleted* table is an implementation detail -- a workaround of sorts for performance.

Some databases, like PostgreSQL 10, can gracefully do this under the hood with [*List Partioning*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html). In doing so, the "deleted" values are stored in a different partition (another distinct table is made available to the user), but it doesn't get in the way.

```
CREATE TABLE offers (...) PARTITION BY LIST (status);
CREATE TABLE offers_deleted PARTITION OF offers
  FOR VALUES IN ('deleted');
```

Now you could query offers `WHERE status='deleted'`, and under the hood it would focus on just that one partition. Remove that predicate, and you'd query all of the partitions of offers. Or, you could query `offers_deleted` directly.

Even there though, my advice would generally be it's bad practice to move data because the status is deleted or because it's archived, **unless performance demands it.** Then you don't do it because you want to, you do it because you have to.