# Assessing the normal form for a relation with a multi-valued attribute

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory, dependencies

Assume that you have designed the following schema of relations:

- `COURSES (CID, CNAME)`
- `STUDENTS(SID, SNAME, FAV_CIDS)`

However, **you can not have a relation with set valued attributes** (Did not really understand what was meant by this) and you
need to convert it to a normal form. What is the normal form and the resulting schema?

We are studying SQL at school. Could not really make out which normal form this was in and functional dependencies.

Comment: Hint: Take a closer look at `FAV_CIDS`.

Comment: Yoy may find [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/135941/63644) of help.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to know what's the relationship between those two entities: `Courses` and `Students`. But, you also need to know the abstraction of those entities into your database schema; we all know that a `Student` could be enrolled in many `Courses`, and a `Course` could contain many `Students`. The relationship between them are **many-to-many**.

The way to enforce a many-to-many relationship is by creating a table apart that will store as Foreign Keys the `Students`, and `Courses` Primary Keys. Both foreign keys will compound the table's primary key. This will gives to you the flexibility to store many courses, and many students.

However, check below how the tables should look like:

- `Courses(CourseId (PK), CourseName)`
- `Students(StudentId (PK), StudentName)`
- `StudentsCourses(StudentId (FK)(PK), CourseId (FK)(PK))`