# One column link to others

Tags: mysql, database-design

I always search my problem with different search terms but the problem I am facing now I can't express this in search keyword. So instead I came here to ask directly from humans as machines were unable to what I exactly means.

So coming to scenario:

I have database with having `table_item` and `table_item_linked`. `table_item` has many items. User come and add item(s). Later other user came and `link` one item with different item via a form with two `dropdown`.

What I did so far is:

```
Structure of `table_item`:
- item_id (Primary) 
- others..
```

.

```
Structure of `table_item_linked`:
- linked_id (Primary) 
- item_id (Foreign key referencing -> item_id of table_item)
- linked_items (here I need to store ids of linked items)
- linked_by (referencing to user_id of user_table)
- linked_timestamp (timestamp)
```

If I have items like: 
`A` `B` `C` `D` `E` `F` `G` `H`

When I link `D` with `G`

I can successfully fetch `G` when I am fetching `D` or vice versa. But problem came when I

Link `H` with `G`

So I must fetch `D` `H` while fetching `G`.

It is like a multiple relation.

Guys I know there must be professional way to do it. I will like to have any guidance. I can even change my database structure.

**PS:** 
Please don't suggest to add #tag as one item is exactly similar to the other linked.

Comment: You might find of help [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135966/63644).

Answer (score 1):

Decide which you type of "relationship" each "link" is:  "1:1", "1:many", or "many:many".

1:1 should be represented by having the columns in the same table.  (There are exceptions, but you aren't there yet.

1:many is implemented via an id of the "1" in the "many" table.  Example:  A `person` owns "many" `cars`.  The `cars` table has a column `person_id` to say who it is owned by.

many:many needs an extra table with ids of both of the tables.  Example:  `students` and `classes`:

```
CREATE TABLE WhoTakesWhat (
     student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     class_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(student_id, class_id),
     INDEX(class_id, student_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I encourage you to be thinking in terms of SQL; you will eventually have to use it.

Meanwhile:

A "database" contains several "tables".
A "table" is a set of "rows" and "columns".
"Columns" tend to be dissimilar (`id`, `name`, `date`, ...)
"Rows" are different instances of what is being stored in the table (various "students" in the table named `students`)

Comment: As suggested by @Akina I decide to go for `Many to Many Relationship` and I am going to do it like `linked_from=D, linked_to=G` and `linked_from=G, linked_to=H`. I will do Self Join to join `table_item` to itself. So I am not sure how will I fetch other linked items. Do I need to search for id in `linked_from` first and then `linked_to` ? What if I came with two similar ids (duplicate) how will I overcome this? Can you plz edit answer and wrote query so that I can accept it. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @fwd82 - Don't do many:many if it is only 1:many.